# Storing several unique numbers as a reverse-engineerable integer

Tags: logic, integers

First off I would like to apologise, I'm sure there are questions about this already by I lack the correct terminology or mathematical knowledge to find what I am looking for using Google search so I will explain what I am trying to do in the hopes someone can tell me what this is called?

By only using numbers in a sequence n=n*2 (1,2,4,8,16...) you can add your unique numbers together in a way that you can deconstruct the total back into it's parts. (e.g. 20 can only be made of 16 and 4).

I'm trying to do this for as many unique numbers as possible but I'm limited to a storage integer of 2^32(-1) which I think only gives me 32 unique numbers.

What I'm wondering is, is there any more efficient way to store more information about which unique numbers are present or not in an integer of this size limit? I suspect not but I thought I would ask in case someone has some brilliant solution I haven't thought of.

Many thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each of your unique numbers can either be "present" or "not present" then you need one bit of information for each number. So the maximum number of "present"/"not present" options that you can encode in a 32-bit integer is indeed 32. Think of the 32-bit integer as 32 switches, each of which can be either on or off (which is, roughly, the way that a computer internally stores a 32-bit integer).

Answer (score 1):

If you have $n$ numbers and need to express **all possible combinations** of which of your initial numbers are present or not, then you need $2^n$ different values you can store, and so with a 32-bit word length you cannot store more than 32 different flags.

However, if your needs are *lower* than "all possible combinations" -- for example, if you know you will never need to have more than 3 of the flags set at the same time, then you can come up with a scheme that allows a greater choice of original numbers.

For example you can store up to $3$ numbers between $1$ and $1624$ by encoding $(a,b,c)$ as $a\cdot1625^2+b\cdot 1625+c$. And you could go somewhat higher than $1624$ at the cost of a more complex representation, given that you don't want to distinguish between order or repetitions.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info! In this case sadly there will be cases where all 32 numbers are present at once. I think I'm going to have to rethink this method and do something else.